# In my Magento store have 400000 above product. It is taking time to re-indexing any solution

Tags: magento2, database, product-reindexing

I have Magento 2.4.2-p1 store. where have 400,000 above products it uploaded by Magmi extension.
Re-indexing taking too much  time. Have any solution for fast re-indexing. Can I increase the values of ram or MYSQL memory etc. or change engine.

For your information I am doing single single re-indexing even though it taking time.
php bin/magento indexer:reindext indexingforproduct or inventory etc.

Please help.

Comment: My store has 500,000+ products and I am running into the same issue. I have even tried this paid extension "Improved Asynchronous Reindexing for Magento 2". But still, I have to be patient until the index completes.

Comment: @puneet Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.